# Adding Disk to Degraded RAID1 Array

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, raid, mdadm

I am trying to add a disk (sdc1) to a degraded RAID1 array (md126), but I don't know how to proceed. Any help will be appreciated because I don't want to lose any of the data on the drive.

[Output isn't formatted well in the post, so a screencap is attached for clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMbKx.png)

> `cat /proc/mdstat`

```
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md126 : active raid1 sdd[0]
      9766433792 blocks super external:/md127/0 [2/1] [_U]

md127 : inactive sdd[0](S)
      2940 blocks super external:imsm

unused devices: <none>
```

> `lsblk`

```
NAME           MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda              8:0    0   1.9T  0 disk  
├─sda1           8:1    0   500M  0 part  
├─sda2           8:2    0   1.9T  0 part  
└─sda3           8:3    0   455M  0 part  
sdb              8:16   0   1.9T  0 disk  
├─sdb1           8:17   0 238.4M  0 part  /boot
└─sdb2           8:18   0   1.9T  0 part  
  └─sdb2_crypt 253:0    0   1.9T  0 crypt /
sdc              8:32   0   9.1T  0 disk  
└─sdc1           8:33   0   9.1T  0 part  
sdd              8:48   0   9.1T  0 disk  
└─md126          9:126  0   9.1T  0 raid1 
  └─md126p1    259:2    0   9.1T  0 md    /mnt/10TB
sde              8:64   0 447.1G  0 disk  
├─sde1           8:65   0   450M  0 part  
├─sde2           8:66   0   100M  0 part  
├─sde3           8:67   0    16M  0 part  
└─sde4           8:68   0 446.6G  0 part  
nvme0n1        259:0    0   1.1T  0 disk
```

Answer (score 1):

Read `man dmraid`. It says, in part:

```
   {-R| --rebuild} RAID-set [device-path]
          Rebuild  raid  array after a drive has failed and a new drive is added.  For Intel chipset based systems, there are two methods in which a new drive is added to
          the system.

          1. Using OROM to identify a new drive
              During system reboot, enter OROM and mark the new drive as the rebuild drive.
              After booting to the OS, use the dmraid command to rebuild.

              Example: dmraid -R raid_set

          2. Using dmraid to identify a new drive
              Boot to the OS and use the dmraid command with the new drive as the second parameter.

              Example: dmraid -R raid_set /dev/sdc

          3. Using hot spare drive
              Mark a drive as hot spare using the "dmraid -f isw -S" command. Then use the dmraid command to start the rebuild.

              Example: dmraid -R raid_set
```

Comment: Also, could you have a look [here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17952/please-read-complaints-of-rep-1-users-more-carefully)?  **:(**